# Is it possible to pull all messages contained in an Azure Servicebus Topic into an app?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azureservicebus

The only method I see to pull messages from a topic is SubscriptionClient.OnMessage(), which seems to only trigger if the topic receives a new message.

Queues have the QueueClient.Receive() method for this purpose, but topics don't seem to have this capability.

Am I missing something?

Comment: A topic can have multiple subscriptions. So to receive all the messages (Don't really know what you mean exactly), you need to get all the messages from all the subscriptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, as Sean Feldman said, ***messages are not received from the topic directly***. Besides, if you’d like to receive and process all messages, you could create a subscription with the default (MatchAll) filter, which will place all messages that published to the topic in the subscription's virtual queue, and then you could  receive and process messages from that subscription in your application. [This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-topics-subscriptions#what-are-service-bus-topics-and-subscriptions) describes how to use Service Bus topics and subscriptions with examples, please refer to it.

Additionally, if necessary, please remember to check and process the dead-letter messages.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `SubscriptionClient.OnMessage()` actually does go through all existing messages on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Messages cannot be received from a topic, only sent to. Topic is used in conjunctions with subscriptions to receive messages.

Queues and [subscriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.subscriptionclient) support OnMessage API. This, though, won't give you all the messages, but instead will give one message at a time X the concurrency level you'll set with [`OnMessageOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.onmessageoptions).

An alternative approach would be to receive batches (see [`ReceiveBatchAsync(Int32, TimeSpan)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.subscriptionclient)). This will allow you handle more than one message if that's what you need.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need [MessageReceiver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.core.imessagereceiver?view=azure-dotnet)

```
var message = await messageReceiver.ReceiveAsync();
await messageReceiver.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);
```